# How can I make button grow within a certain range(minheight - maxheight)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a range of values for a button and let the grid change the buttons current height/width when the main window changes it's dimensions(grow together and shrink together).
But while I'm resizing the window the button's dimensions stay the same.
What I'm I doing wrong why doesn't the button's dimensions changes?

```
<Window x:Class="WPFLabTestButtonSizeAftersetMinWidth.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="40" MinWidth="100" MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="400">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to **Stretch** instead of centre and it will stretch according to the available space within the limits defined by you.